# Struts2 interceptor (After View Rendered Interceptor ) is not called before the redirect request comes back from browser

Tags: struts2, interceptor

In a webapp we have transaction management using struts2 interceptor

pseudo code of the interceptor

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    TransactionService.startTransaction();
    invocation.invoke();
    TransactionService.commitTransaction();
}
```

when the action returns 'redirect' (302), sometimes the redirected request comes to the server before 'TransactionService.commitTransaction()' is called. ( looks like  network call is faster than stack unwinding )

below log message captured explains this

```
2017-10-04 09:18:37,693 [task-37] DEBUG (interceptors)  TransactionInterceptor begin
2017-10-04 09:18:37,949 [task-38] DEBUG (interceptors)  TransactionInterceptor begin
2017-10-04 09:18:37,963 [task-37] DEBUG (interceptors)  TransactionInterceptor commit 
2017-10-04 09:18:37,955 [task-38] ERROR (interceptors)  SecurityInterceptor: Failed to execute Action:
```

in the above log Task-37 ( thread ) suppose to save/update some records in DB and issue a redirect to refresh the view, its interceptor will commit the transaction.

But the redirect thread ( Task - 38 ) reached the server before commit happened.

I am looking at PreResultListener or 'Chain Result'. ( both options have its own issues)  I greatly appreciate any input to solve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should not write your own interceptor, if you can't.

Comment: its bit old code, so i cannot do much there

Comment: you cannot do anything with this code because this code doesn't work

Comment: How / Why there are different threads?

Comment: Action returns 302 redirect. some cases ( occurred randomly, rarely  ) browser made the redirected request before the stock unwinding happened (so that transaction service interceptor can commit). That is why two threads. In this case the redirected request expected to display the last committed data-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code, kind a worked around with PreResultListener.

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    invocation.addPreResultListener(new PreResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void beforeResult(ActionInvocation invocation, String resultCode) {
            try {

                // commit based on the resultCode comparision 
                if (StringUtils.equals(resultCode,"302_redirect")  {
                    TransactionService.commitTransaction();
                }
                // or commparision based on the redirect handler 
                // Class names are from struts-default.xml
                /*
                String resultConfigClassName = invocation.getProxy().getConfig().getResults().get(resultCode).getClassName();
                if (StringUtils.equals(resultConfigClassName,"org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult")
                        || StringUtils.equals(resultConfigClassName, "org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult")) {
                    TransactionService.commitTransaction();
                }
                */
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // Ignore don't do anything
            }
        }
    });

    TransactionService.startTransaction();
    invocation.invoke();
    TransactionService.commitTransaction();
}
```